# JavaScript clean-URL from page Title field

Tags: php, javascript, regex, short-url

I have a field in my form in which I provide the name of my new page which I'm adding to my CMS.

I have a PHP code here which lowers case, sets '-' instead of ' ', and makes a short URL look nice:

```
$clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_| -]/", '', $clean);
$clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
$clean = preg_replace("/[\/_| -]+/", '-', $clean);
```

I am NOT EXPERIENCED with JavaScript's RegEx, so can anyone help me convert this piece of PHP code to JavaScript.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All in one go:

```
var string = "The   new page's future name!"
,   clean = string.replace(/(^\-+|[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_| -]+|\-+$)/g, '')
            .toLowerCase()
            .replace(/[\/_| -]+/g, '-')
;
console.log(clean); // "the-new-pages-future-name"
```

The first `replace` takes care of all unwanted characters AND trims all extra dashes at start and end. The second replace replaces all (groups of) slashes, underscores, pipes and spaces by a hyphen.

Comment: this one rules the world! thanks dog!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var string = "Some string to clean up";
string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
```

In my browser console it yields

```
"some-string-to-clean-up"
```

Comment: yea, but what if: "Some   string to   clean up", I get: "some---string-to---clean-up"

Comment: I mean if I set more than two empty spaces, I'd get the response as up above

Comment: Added + to the regex to capture multiple undesired characters in a row. Gives me: `var string = "Some         string to clean up";
string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
"some-string-to-clean-up"`

Comment: thanks jxpx777, this one did the trick partially!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to convert between charsets in javascript.  Here is a very literal version of the rest of it.

```
clean = clean.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_| -]/g, '');
clean = clean.replace(/^[\-]+/, ''); // trim start
clean = clean.replace(/[\-]+$/, ''); // trim end
clean = clean.toLowerCase();
clean = clean.replace(/[\/_| -]+/g, '-');
```

Or in one statement

```
 clean = clean.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_| -]/g, '').replace(/^[\-]+/, '').replace(/[\-]+$/, '').toLowerCase().replace(/[\/_| -]+/g, '-');
```

Comment: there's " string ".trim() or jQuery's $.trim() to trim strings... but thanks dawg!

Comment: trim in js just removes white space.  The trim you used in php is trying to remove leading and trailing dashes.